# Text Overflow in main

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface

Text overflows to right side tab in some questions

Browser: Chrome 27
OS: Windows 8

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17253797/1

What I see:
[image]

Here is the problematic part:

$(document).ready(function(){$("#001,#002,#003,#004,#005,#006,#007,#008,#009,#010,#011,#012,#013,#014,#015,#016,#017,#018,#019,#020,#021,#022,#023,#024,#025,#026,#027,#028,#029,").css("display", "none");});

Comment: I've verified zoom is on 100% and tried in incognito mode to make sure it's not caused by an extension.

Comment: So format it as code like it should be and there won't be a problem...

Comment: Umm... it seems to overflow in this question, too

Comment: @animuson It's still a UI bug. The text can be wrapped, or trimming can be applied. Jan - That was the point of the 'problematic' part.

Comment: @animuson sometimes such post is generated by our bot without being intended by its user. Also, such post could me malicious.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It doesn't need to be. There is no *legitimate* use-case where a user would need plain-text that long that the system would need to wrap it. So there's no reason to account for it. Formatting correctly is the proper solution.

Comment: @animuson I've seen Java class names in packages that were that long.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){$("#001,#002,#003,#004,#005,#006,#007,#008,#009,#010,#011,#012,#013,#014,#015,#016,#017,#018,#019,#020,#021,#022,#023,#024,#025,#026,#027,#028,#029,").css("display", "none");}); Doesn't seem to do it for a comment.

Comment: @animuson malice, undesired results of javascript evaluation by our bot, copy-paste of minified/golfed code...

Comment: @animuson So this is a markdown parser bug?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Perhaps. Formatting is still the correct solution. Running the entire post through Markdown *again* after you've stripped the invalid HTML isn't exactly an effective way of parsing things. The problem doesn't occur if the `<script>` tags aren't there.

Comment: @animuson Based on that same argument - why not let all the users do the syntax highlighting themselves using tags like <blue> or <green>? I mean - it's all a matter of formatting. This _is_ a bug with the markdown parser. The correct course of action IMO is first to report it (which I did). Then when its time arrives after more urgent stuff is fixed either categorize it as expected behavior (closing this as bydesign) or fixing it. I'm for fixing it, after all it _is_ a bug and it causes an unpleasent visual experience until an edit is made, but that's not why I posted this (again, reporting).

Comment: Also, the fix should be quite easy: adding the right CSS to all relevant places.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's not a CSS problem. The fact that the code is actually surrounded by `<script>` tags prevents it from being placed inside a paragraph, which would break it to a new line.

Comment: @animuson then it looks like a Markdown bug. If a fix is not easy, CSS could still be used as a workaround

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it does it for comments on mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We twiddled around the wrapping css in the past weeks, and now it seems not to happen anymore.

Feel free to ping me under this (or better, open a new bug) if you can reproduce the problem.